# What the function of java.awt.font.TextAttribute in android?

Tags: android, awt, android-textattributes

I've found a java awt class that called TextAttribute in android, see the link below:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html

but I don't know how it works, does anyone knows?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, no one answered my question... :(
Actually, I've found that there is no use of this class for android development, I've found no class refer it, it's probably a legacy of java AWT, I guess.